# Help with upper estimate for the elementary function $1-\sqrt{1-|x|^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^*$ such that $|x|\le 1$.
Consider the quantity
$$1-\sqrt{1-|x|^2}.$$

Could someone please help me in finding upper and lower estimates for that quantity?

So far, I just observed that
$$1-\sqrt{1-|x|^2} \ge \frac12 |x|^2,$$
so I found a lower estimate (I guess). Could someone please help me in finding an upper one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0 \le y \le 1$ is
$$ 
 \frac 12 y \le 1 - \sqrt{1-y} \le y \, .
$$

- The lower bound follows from $\sqrt{1-y} \le \sqrt{1-y+y^2/4} = 1-y/2$, or from Bernoulli's inequality.
- The upper bound follows from $\sqrt y \ge y$.

Setting $y= x^2$ gives
$$
 \frac 12 x^2 \le  1-\sqrt{1-|x|^2} \le x^2 
$$
for $-1 \le x \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x):=1-\sqrt{1-|x|^2}.$ It is clear that $f(x) \le 1$ for $x$ with $|x| \le 1.$

Furthermore, if $x  \in\mathbb{R}^*$ with $|x|=1$, then $f(x)=1.$ Hence

$$ \max \{f(x): x  \in\mathbb{R}^*, |x| \le 1\}=1.$$